# For a SQL table indexed by time, add rows to fill in missing time indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Currently I have a list of transactions with 3 main dimensions: Keys, Time_Index and Cumulative_Amount.

```
Keys      Time_Index     Cumulative_Amount
100          1          103
100          3          222
101          2          101
```

I'm trying to "populate all the Time_Index". In this case, although nothing happened for key 100 at time 2, I'd like to populate it. The result should be as below (Max time index = 3):

```
Keys      Time_Index     Cumulative_Amount
100          1          103
100          2          103
100          3          222
101          2          101
101          3          101
```

Note that I'm not populating time 1 for key 101 because the earliest time for which key 101 existed is time 2. I'm populating each key from it's earliest existence until max_time_index = 3.

Answer (score 0):

I would first generate a list of all possible combinations of `Keys` and `Time_Index`, followed by a usual `RIGHT / LEFT OUTER JOIN` where you can do a condition for `NULL`. Something like this:

```
with t as
(
    select distinct x = a.number, y = b.number
    from master..[spt_values] a
    cross join 
    master..[spt_values] b
    where a.number between 1 and 4
    and b.number between 100 and 103
)
select
    case when x.Cumulative_Amount is null then -1 else x.Cumulative_Amount  end, t.Keys, t.Time_Index
from dbo.myTable x 
right join t on t.Keys = x.Keys
```